# Appending Value Makes File Disappear from Folder

Tags: java, file, filenames

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;


public class AppendTool {
public static void main(String[] args){
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Directory to Append Values: ");
    String dirInput = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input value to append to Directory Files: ");
    String valInput = sc.nextLine();
    
    sc.close();
    
    File path = new File(dirInput);

    File [] files = path.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        if (files[i].isFile()){ //this line weeds out other directories/folders
            System.out.println(files[i]);
            
            int where = files[i].getName().lastIndexOf(".");
            String result = valInput + files[i].getName().substring(0, where) + files[i].getName().substring(where);
            System.out.println(result);
            File dest = new File(result);
            files[i].renameTo(dest);
            System.out.println(files[i]);
            }   
    }
    }
  }
```

This tool is designed to append a value to the beginning of the filename for every filename in a directory. It seems to append the value as it should, but it deletes the files from the directory rather than rename the existing file within the same directory. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To rename a file in the same directory, you can use:
Files.move(source, source.resolveSibling("newName.txt"),
StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

Your result variable is weird, you can just:
String result = valInput + files[i].getName();